# Cron: possibility to specify a hours to start/stop on a specific day

Tags: cron

What is the crontab syntax for specifying running hours/minutes based on the day of the week in a single entry?

There's a task which needs to be executed every /1 minute from Monday,01:00 to Saturday,01:00, so after specifying the days (1-6) I still have to exclude 00:00-00:59 from Monday and 01:00-23:59 from Sunday.

I don't want to keep it done with three entries instead of one; doing additional time check via some wrapper script is also not a good option.

Cron flavor: vixie-cron, could be changed to another if required.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this cron isn't that smart as you mention you will need 3 lines

```
#Mon
* 1-23 * * 1 task
#Tue to Sat
* * * * 2-6 task
# Sun 
* 1 * * 0 task
```

or something similar.

Comment: Should be `2-6` for Tuesday to Saturday. `2,6` is Tuesday and Saturday